# Weird Potential Divider Diagram

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage, batteries

[image]

How does the above circuit work? My textbook only has potential divider circuits such that there is only one output voltage. Such as this one.

[image]

Could we replace the arrowed line in the uppermost diagram with two lines? This is the only way the above diagram would make sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

The components (lamps ?) at P and Q simply give you access to both the reduced voltage from one side of the potential divider and its complement from the other side. So if the voltage across P is $V_P$ then the voltage across Q is $12-V_P$ because we know that $V_P + V_Q = 12$ volts.

Answer (score 0):

The $12\,\rm V$ is divided between the two bulb but what that division is dependents of the relative resistances of the bulbs and the resistor $AB$.

If the resistances of the bulbs is much less than that of resistor $AB$ then moving the slider along resistor $AB$ will in the main have very little effect on the voltages across each of the bulbs except when the slider is very near or at one of the ends.

If, on the other hand, the resistances of the bulbs is much greater than that of resistor $AB$ then moving the slider along resistor $AB$ will in the main have a very large effect on the voltages across each of the bulbs.

The other thing to note is that in your second diagram there is nothing connected to the terminals $V_{\rm out}$ so the "normal, no load" potential divider equation will be correct.

However, if current is drawn from the central contact, ie the potential divider is connected to a load, then the analysis of the circuit has to be done from first principles.

Answer (score 0):

> Could we replace the arrowed line in the uppermost diagram with two
> lines? This is the only way the above diagram would make sense to me.

You could replace the upper diagram with two lower diagrams, with each of the lower diagrams addressing two potentiometer outputs, one for each lamp load P and Q. See the diagrams below.

Note that moving the potentiometer to the right or left only increases and decreases the resistance and thus voltage output to P and Q, with the sum of the voltage outputs equaling the voltage input to the potentiometer.

Hope this helps.

[image]